# could not update in session data in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to update session data (List type)using a controller. but it's not working.it gives me an error.

Here is my code:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Cart()
        {

            List<Spray> spray = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Spray>>("spray");
           
            
            if (spray == null)
            {
                spray = new List<Spray>();
            }
            return View(spray);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Cart(int id)
        {
            List<Spray> spray = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Spray>>("spray");
           
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (spray[i].Id.Equals(id))
                {
                    spray[i].Quantity++;
                }
            }
           return RedirectToAction(nameof(Cart));

        }
```

View

```
@using HuddsonBay.Models
@model List<Spray>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Cart";
}

<h1>Your Cart</h1>
<br />



<div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Product Type</th>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/@item.Image" width="200px" height="150px" />
                </td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Price</td>
                <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                <td>
                    <partial name="_QuantityPartial" model="@item.Id" />
                </td>

                <td>@item.ProductColor</td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-area="Customer" asp-action="Remove" asp-controller="SprayShow" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="SprayShow" class="btn btn-primary">Back To Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <h3>Total Amount</h3>
        <h3>Grand Total : @Model.Sum(c => c.Price)</h3>
        <a asp-area="Customer" asp-action="Checkout" asp-controller="Order" class="btn btn-info">Process To CheckOut</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

_QuantityPartial.cshtml

```
@model int

<form method="post">
    <td style="width:150px">
        <div class="btn-group">

            @*<a asp-action="Index"  class="btn btn-danger" asp-route-id="@Model">Add</a>*@
            <input type="submit" asp-action="Cart" asp-route-id="@Model" value="+" />
        </div>
    </td>
</form>
```

and here is my output:
[image]

and when I click "+" button, I found an error:
[image]

will be increment or decrement using a controller. How I will solve this.
I am beginner, please help anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List<Spray> spray` in your post method is a new Instance of the list in your session, after change the propertity's value, you need to store the new list again in session. Otherwise it is still the orignally one.

A test example based on your codes:

View:

```
@model List<Spray>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Cart";
}

<h1>Your Cart</h1>
<br />



<div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Price</td>
                    <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                    <td>
                        <partial name="_QuantityPartial" model="@item.Id" />
                    </td>

                    <td>@item.ProductColor</td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-area="Customer" asp-action="Remove" asp-controller="SprayShow" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="SprayShow" class="btn btn-primary">Back To Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <h3>Total Amount</h3>
        <h3>Grand Total : @Model.Sum(c => c.Price)</h3>
        <a asp-area="Customer" asp-action="Checkout" asp-controller="Order" class="btn btn-info">Process To CheckOut</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Cart()
{

    var value = HttpContext.Session.GetString("spray");
    var spray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Spray>>(value);

    if (spray == null)
    {
        spray = new List<Spray>();
    }
    return View(spray);
}


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Cart(int id)
{
    var value = HttpContext.Session.GetString("spray");
    var spray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Spray>>(value);

    for (int i = 0; i < spray.Count; i++)
    {
        if (spray[i].Id.Equals(id))
        {
            spray[i].Quantity++;
        }
    }
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("spray", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(spray));

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Cart));

}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have hardcoded 10 in your for loop. If u have less than 10 items in your list it will overflow.
Change to this (or use a foreach)

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Cart(int id)
{
    List<Spray> spray = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Spray>>("spray");
       
    for (int i = 0; i < spray.Count; i++)
    {
        if (spray[i].Id.Equals(id))
        {
            spray[i].Quantity++;
        }
    }
   return RedirectToAction(nameof(Cart));

}
```

Another option is to skip the loop and do like this instead

```
public IActionResult Cart(int id)
{
     List<Spray> spray = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Spray>>("spray");

     var item = spray.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
     if(item != null)
     {
         item.Quantity++;
     }

     return RedirectToAction(nameof(Cart));
}
```

Comment: still not working.when i clicked "+" button,value did not increase/decrase.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem maybe not be your Session. Is about the number of the items from the `List<Spray>` spray. The exception is about the length of the  `spray` list. Your `for` goes always up to 10 and is possible that you have less items in your list and that is why you have that Out of Range exception.